# Cannot Lazy Load Module from node_modules packages

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, tsconfig

**Motive::**
Create a App Shell with Angular CLI and define routes that lazy load modules from packages inside `node_modules`.

**Procedure::**
Created a app shell using Angular CLI. 
Referenced the routes in `app.routes.ts`

```
const appShellRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'sample',  loadChildren : './sample#SampleModule' }// location in src/app,
  {path : 'visual-designer', loadChildren: 'visual-designer#VisualDesignerModule'} //location in node_modules
];
```

and as i need to configure tsconfigs with `path` & `include`
**tsconfig.app.json**

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "module": "es2015",
    "types": [],
    "paths": {
      "@angular/*": [
        "../node_modules/@angular/*"
      ],
      "visual-designer": [
        "../node_modules/visual-designer/*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "../src/**/*",
    "../node_modules/visual-designer/*"
  ]
}
```

and in the tsconfig.json added the `include` at root level

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

**Problem::**
After this i get this error

[image]

Asking me to configure the tsconfigs via `include` or `files`

What exactly have i missed? Looked at so many issue on git found only this one relevant. [Git cli Issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9142)

Angular CLI Version : 1.6.7

Comment: There is an open issue at angular-cli git repo https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6373. I'm looking for a fix aswell.

Comment: Any update on it?

Comment: It's pretty much in the same state.